# DUP! problem on ping

Tags: networking

I've got the following problem when trying to ping a specific host:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.32.119: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=0.884 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.32.119: icmp_seq=7 ttl=127 time=2.10 ms (DUP!)
```

I tried to get IP addresses by MAC:

```
root@ws100:~# ip neighbor | grep "48:5b:39:a6:c5:3a" | cut -d" " -f1
192.168.32.119
```

As you can see I get only one IP returned so no duplicated hosts are shown...

Is there a way how to get what's the problem?

Comment: Your host are on ESXi?

Comment: Nope. My host is real PC.

Answer (score 2):

DUP means duplicate packet.

From `man ping`:

```
    Duplicate and Damaged Packets

    ping will report duplicate and damaged packets. Duplicate packets should
never occur, and seem to be caused by inappropriate link-level 
retransmissions. Duplicates may occur in many situations and are rarely 
(if ever) a good sign, although the presence of low levels of duplicates 
may not always be cause for alarm.

    Damaged packets are obviously serious cause for alarm and often indicate 
broken hardware somewhere in the ping packet's path (in the network or in the hosts).
```

There are different reasons for this, did you capture your network traffic with an interface in promiscous mode? Sometimes this is the reason for dupplicated packets.

Comment: Well, I know what DUP means. I have no idea how to fix it. And I don't capture my network traffic with an interface in promiscous mode.

Comment: You have only one  switch? Also you have only one cable per pc connected to switch?

Comment: Well, the target PC inserted into the 3rd switch actually (I have more than one switch). And in this switсh more than one cable (from that PC) are inserted of course.

Comment: Maybe you have double path from pc1 to pc2. Try ping with only one switch between pc1 and pc2. If you then don't have problem, problem is for sure  in double path. Eliminate extra cable's and problem be probably solved.

Answer (score 1):

Was receiving the `DUP!` error when pinging an ubuntu 20.04.5 server on a vmware esxi 6.7 host.

`64 bytes from x.x.x.x: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=2.31 ms (DUP!)`

The esxi host had 4 NICs connected to a Cisco switch and the 4 switch ports were not configured as a port channel. The host had `Route based on IP hash` selected on the vSwitch, which should only be enabled when using EtherChannel or a port-channel. Changed it to `Route based on originating port ID` and the `DUP!` was resolved.

Then configured the 4 switch ports as a port-channel and changed back to IP hash method and all is well.